# Matlab - input argument is not defined

Tags: matlab

I have this very simple function in matlab.

```
function [f]=f1(a, xx)
xx
f = -exp(-a(1)*(xx(1)-1)^2 - a(2)*(xx(2)-1)^2) - exp(-a(1)*(xx(1)+1)^2 -a(2)*(xx(2)+1)^2);
```

It does print the value of xx, and then complains "Input argument "xx" is undefined".
How is this possible? What's going on?

I call the function with feval
Here is another example that doesn't use feval. I get the error
Input argument "xxx" is undefined. Please help me, I have no idea what's going on and I'm stuck.

I have:
function [ ans ] = f2( xxx )
xxx
   %f2 is 1/(1+xxx^2), the function for problem 2
   ans = 1 / (1+xxx^2);
end

one file is neville.m

Q = neville(x,xi,f2)
%NEVILLE implements Neville method for polynomial interpolation

nplus1 = max(size(xi));
Q = zeros(nplus1);
Q(:,1) =f2(xi);

for i = 2 : nplus1
    for j = 2 : i
        Q(i, j) = ((x - xi(i-j)) * Q(i, j-1) - (x - x(i))*Q(i-1, j-1)) / (x(i) - x(i-j));
    end;
end;

The other file is neville_driver.m
N = 6;
aux = [0:6];
xi = -5 + 10*aux/N;

Q = neville(4, xi, f2)

Comment: how are you calling your function?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're passing a function `f2` into `neville.m`. Try using `Q=neville(x,xi,@f2);` Also, if `xi` is a vector, you should use element wise multiplication (and raising it to the nth power) using a dot (`.`) before the operation, else it will give an error. i.e., `1/(1+xxx.^2)`.

Comment: So, the idea is that in neville_driver.m I want to use f2 as fi, but in neville.m I want to have a function at argument. How exactly do I do this?

Comment: fi is a function parameter. In this particular situation, I am passing f2 in the place of fi.

Comment: I also get this error message:Attempt to execute SCRIPT neville as a function. What is going on???

Comment: it means that you have not defined neville as a function. at the moment, it's just a plain matlab script, which you're probably trying to execute as a function either by passing variables or by using a function handle. this will result in an error. you should rewrite neville as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Is xx a function?  Because the syntax `xx(2)` is a function call. Did you mean `xx*2` ?

Edit: your first example code works fine for me:

```
feval(@f1,[2,2],[10,10]);
```

Prints xx and then the result.

Edit2: and the code for f1:

```
function [f]=f1(a, xx)
xx
f = -exp(-a(1)*(xx(1)-1)^2-a(2)*(xx(2)-1)^2)-exp(-a(1)*(xx(1)+1)^2-a(2)*(xx(2)+1)^2);
end
```

Comment: Perhaps I should use handle when I use f2 as function argument?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not necessary.